# Issues with SBTableAlert.. It shows the alert but not UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I don't know if anyone has any experience with `SBTableAlert`. It looks awesome, but not much documentation.

It is also not calling any of the functions that `UITableView` would use. Can any one help  with following code.

```
//load the bookmarks and setup the popup
SBTableAlert *bookmarkAlert;

bookmarkAlert = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jump to:" cancelButtonTitle:@"Back" messageFormat:nil];
[bookmarkAlert setDelegate:self];
//[bookmarkAlert setDataSource:self];

NSString *settingsicon = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"gear" ofType:@"png"];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:settingsicon] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:bookmarkAlert action:@selector(show)];
```

Comment: What are you running into in getting this to work?

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you are not setting the datasource.  This would be the obvious reason you're not getting what you are looking for, unless you set this later on.

Comment: I actually don't remember what I did to make it work, but I completed that project some time ago after a lot of exhausting work.

Comment: Yeah I am having a "fun" time with it too.